# Mapping uneven lists help - Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to create a function where I pair elements from two different lists. Of course, my first idea is to use the map function which works for lists of the same size, but if I wanted to pair two lists of different sizes and replace the missing elements with say an *, how would  I go about doing so?

Answer (score 3):

You could think of it this way:

Your recursive function, call it `zip-uneven`, will take two lists A and B and return a list of two-element lists. At each stage we will only think about the front of the lists, leaving the rest of each for a recursive call to `zip-uneven` with the rest of the lists. There are four possibilities:

1. Both lists are empty (`null?`).

   This is your base case, which should return an empty list.
2. List B is empty while list A still has items

   In this case, you want to return a list whose first element is a list of `(car a)` and your dummy `*` symbol and whose other elements are constructed by recurring using the rest of list A (`cdr a`) and the "rest" of list B (which is still the empty list, `'()`).

   That's to say, the return value of `zip-uneven` will be a `cons` of `(list (car a) '*)` and the result of a recursive call `(zip-uneven ...)`.
3. Just like case 2, but with the empty and non-empty lists reversed
4. Neither list is empty. This will look a lot like cases (2) and (3), but you'll recur on the `cdr` of both lists.

If one list is shorter than the other, eventually as you `cdr` down the lists it will reduce to case (2) or case (3); whether the lists are different lengths or not, eventually the recursion will reduce to case (1) in which case the 'rest of the list' is `'()` and we are done with the recursion.

Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1):

My answer has two parts: first, I'll implement a `map-shortest`, then I'll tweak that to implement `map-longest` since that's (barely) more involved. Both solutions require [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html); the `map-shortest` solution uses `unfold` and `any`, and the `map-longest` solution uses `unfold` and `every`. (By the way, SRFI 1 also provides a `map` that works the same as `map-shortest`.)

First, `map-shortest`:

```
(define (map-shortest func . lists)
  (unfold (lambda (lists)
            (any null? lists))
          (lambda (lists)
            (apply func (map car lists)))
          (lambda (lists)
            (map cdr lists))
          lists))
```

This is straightforward:

1. It checks if any of the lists are empty. If so, stop.
2. Otherwise, the `car` of each list is used as arguments to call the function with.
3. Then, `cdr` through each list for the next iteration.

Now, `map-longest` is a variation of that, except that you have to deal with the fact that some lists may already be empty:

```
(define (map-longest func filler . lists)
  (define (car-or-filler x)
    (if (pair? x) (car x) filler))
  (define (cdr-or-null x)
    (if (pair? x) (cdr x) '()))
  (unfold (lambda (lists)
            (every null? lists))
          (lambda (lists)
            (apply func (map car-or-filler lists)))
          (lambda (lists)
            (map cdr-or-null lists))
          lists))
```

So, this is quite similar to `map-shortest`, with three differences:

1. The termination condition is `every`, not `any`: we stop when every list is empty.
2. Instead of `car`, we use `car-or-filler`, which gets the `car` if the list isn't empty, or the filler otherwise.
3. Instead of `cdr`, we use `cdr-or-null`, which gets the `cdr` if the list isn't empty, or the empty list otherwise. (At this point, I can hear Common Lispers laughing: in Common Lisp, `(cdr '())` returns `'()`; not so in Scheme.)

Simple enough, hopefully? :-)

Answer (score -2):

Use a WHILE loop to...wait, crap.

Okay, use a FOR loop to...uh...

In all honesty:  I would have a helper function that compares the lengths of each list, and then appends asterisks onto the end of the shorter one until it is the same size.

So, pseudo-code because I can't remember all of the specifics of Scheme:

```
    (define helperFunction(list1, list2)
      first = list-length(list1)
      second = list-length(list2)
      if(first > second)
         asteriskPopulate(list2, first-second)
      else if(second > first)
         asteriskPopulate(list1, second-first)
     )
```

Edit for additional clarity:

```
    (define list-length
       (lambda (l)
       (cond
          ((null? l) 0)
          (#t (+ 1 (list-length (cdr l)))))))
```

Edit for explanation (Sorry!):

The helperFunction takes in two lists of possibly uneven lengths and sets two variables firstLength and secondLength to represent the lengths of the two lists.  This is achieved through the list-length code (taken with appreciation from [Scheme Tutorial](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps112/Spring03/languages/scheme/SchemeTutorialB.html)).  This code works through embedded recursion by recursively CDR'ing off elements and adding one to the final result.

Once we have the two lengths we can compare, calling a separate function asteriskPopulate with the shorter of the two lists, and the difference in lengths.  Inside that function we will simply append a series of asterisks until our difference variable (first minus second or second minus first) is 0.  I leave it to you to write that function, should be quick and informative.

And finally, once we have our lists at an even length you can use MAP appropriately.

Comment: Could you explain your Scheme code please? I'm new to the language.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but in this case a straight recursive solution will be more efficient (as well as arguably clearer). To find the lengths of the lists first we have to chase pointers the whole length of each one twice before doing so again using `map`; whereas writing it as a recursive function we can `cdr` down both lists at the same time, constructing the result as we go.

Comment: Both solutions work obviously, but I was hoping for more feedback than "your solution isn't as good as mine" Plus, with something like this, and Scheme in general, efficiency is probably not a concern.

Comment: Fair enough, but one reason for learning Scheme is to learn this style of recursive problem-solving. It comes in handy when you have a problem for which you really do need a recursive solution (or the equivalent) -- like traversing a tree of directories or XML nodes.  Also, singly-linked lists don't exist only in Scheme, and it's worth thinking about efficiency/elegance* even in toy problems just for the practice. *Obviously the two are not always the same thing. ;-)

Comment: I agree that recursion is incredibly useful, and Scheme was where I first encountered it.  However, I would contend that Tail and Embedded are equally useful to know, and that our solutions only differ in the flavor of recursion.